# If $h∈ C^2(\mathbb{R})$, $\exists a∈R $ with $h'(a)=0$, $h''(a)>0$; then $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $h(x)\geq h(a)$ $\forall x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I have trouble to solve the question 3 using 1st and 2nd questions.

1. Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a \in\mathbb{R}$, and $f(a) > 0.$ Prove that there exists $\delta > 0$ so that $f(x) \geq \frac{1}{2}f(a)$ for all $x \in (a -\delta, a + \delta)$.
2. Assume $g$ is continous on $[a, b]$, and $\int_a^b|g(x)| dx = 0$. Prove $g(x) ≡ 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.
3. Assume $h\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and there exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $h'(a)=0$ and $h''(a)>0$. Prove that $\exists\delta>0$ s.t. $h(x)\geq h(a)$ for all $x\in dom f$ with $|x-a|<\delta$.

For the 1st question I chose $\epsilon=\frac{f(a)}{2}$. For the 2nd, the proof comes from the Mean Value Theorem. Can you help me to conclude the 3rd one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware of implication of sign of derivative? If $f'(a) >0$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ that $f(x) < f(a) $ for all $x\in(a-\delta, a) $ and $f(x) >f(a) $ for all $x\in(a, a+\delta) $. Now apply this to $f=h'$ and also use $f(a) =h'(a) =0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply again the Mean Value Theorem to conclude.

By continuity of $h''$, you have $h''(x)>0$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $a$. In particular, $h'$ is increasing (in fact, strictly increasing) on an interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$. And now we apply mean value:

If $x\in (a-\delta,a)$, then there exists $b\in (x,a)$ such that $$\frac{h(x)-h(a)}{x-a}=h'(b)<h'(a)=0$$ and then $h(x)>h(a)$. If $x\in (a,a+\delta)$ the argument is analogous and you get $h(x)>h(a)$ for $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$.

Extra: in case you know (and have proved!) Taylor's theorem: take $\delta>0$ such that $h''(x)>0$ for $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Now, if $|x-a|<\delta$, by Taylor's theorem there exists $b\in (x,a)$ or $b\in (a,x)$ such that $h(x)=h(a)+\frac{1}{2}h''(b)(x-a)^{2}$, from where you get $h(x)>h(a)$ if $|x-a|<\delta$.